# How can I sample within an id range in Pymongo?

Tags: database, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have read [this doc](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html?highlight=aggregate) and [this blog](http://danielhnyk.cz/randomly-choose-n-records-from-mongodb/), and learned that I can sample like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
        { $sample: {size: 20} }, 
        { $match:  {"yourField": valueOrSpecifier} } 
      ])
```

Then I wrote mine:

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
        {"$sample": {"size": 20}}, 
        {"$match": {"_id": {"$gt": 50, "$lt": 100}}}
      ])
```

to sample 20 documents whose _ids are between 50 and 100.

But I get an empty generator. I have checked the collection, and there are 49 samples satisfying this restriction.

Comment: Why you just don't use `$sample` stage after the `$match`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of the pipeline stages really matters here. When you use [**`$sample`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) before the [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) then it filters the data from the 20 document found in the `$sample` stage.

And if you will use [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) before the [**`$sample`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) then it will filter the first document from your all the collection inside the database and will throw 20 document in the `$sample stage.

So finally your pipeline should be something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
  { "$match": { "_id": { "$gt": 50, "$lt": 100 }}},
  { "$sample": { "size": 20 }}
])
```